# Safe characters for allowing file access in a directory

Tags: php, security, file

I've got a PHP script which allows uses to delete certain files in a directory by specifying the file name (via a drop down - but thats easy enough for someone malicious to change). I'm 'cleansing' the file name by doing the following

```
if(preg_match(/'/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]$/'/,$file)) {
    # do stuff to this particular file
}
```

I'm fairly sure that should prevent anyone from getting up to anything nasty, but as the people here have vast amounts of knowledge more then I, I thought I'd ask -- is there a hole here, or will this keep the nasty away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your regex will really help: There are valid characters outside that range that you won't be able to delete this way.

One thing that I would do is do a `realpath()` on the full final path, and check whether it still is a child of your allowed file path. That will prevent `../../` directory traversal attacks, even if they use some special characters. That should already provide fairly good security.

You could also additionally scan the directory using `glob()` and check the results to see whether the requested file is actually in there (that is impossible to circumvent even with the most sneaky directory traversal.)

If you want to be **totally paranoid** about this, you could use a different approach altogether: Don't transfer file names, but list indexes of a list that you specified before. If for example you show this list to the user and save it in a temporary text file or database record:

1. Readme.txt
2. License
3. Readme.doc

and then pass only the (random) ID of the text file or database record, and the number of the file you want to delete:

```
delete.php?list=xasdafdas&index=3
```

you should have a solution that is pretty invulnerable against any conceivable kind of injection and file name tampering.

You would have to store an individual list for every request, as the files can change.

Comment: I'm just worried about them getting out of that directory. Anything in that directory is fair game, and those files can only have a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and . in the file names. I'm wondering if there's still some ingenious way of getting out of the directory or wrecking real havoc when I'm only allowing those characters. But yes, I agree, checking the submitted filename vs the files I want to allow to be deleted is probably safest.

Comment: @Will if you use `realpath()`, you should be fine using the "transfer file names" method. You could also additionally scan the directory using `glob()` and check the results to see whether the requested file is actually in there (that is impossible to circumvent even with the most sneaky directory traversal)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change your regexp in

```
if(preg_match(/'/^[^a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/'/,$file)) {
# do stuff to this particular file
}
```

Comment: Yeah I had the regEx wrong (so do you actually) should be: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/` but the question still stands -- can someone still do something nasty with just those valid characters?

Answer (score 0):

If your filename is not an absolute path, and your always prefix the directory path

```
chdir(...); // change directory to that directory

// make use the $file is not contains '/'
$file = basename($file);

// check $file is not in list of files that you don't allow for delete
if ($file=='index.php' ...)
{
  // do nothing
  return false;
}


if (is_file($file))
{
  unlink($file); // or other actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That regexp will match pretty much anything. Did you mean `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]/` instead? That would still match something like `../../../etc/shadow` though. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/` (or simply `/^[\w\d.]+$/`) is better, or you could just check the filename against the array you created the dropdown from.